# How do you disable User Interaction for a particular UITableView Section

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

I was looking for something similar to :

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO forSection:indexPath.section];
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: and return nil if the indexPath.section refers to the section you don't want to be touchable. This will prevent the cells in that section from being selected

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting userInteractionEnabled to no, could you just not handle the didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

For example in didSelectRowAtIndexPath have an if statement:

```
if(indexPath.section != 1){
     [self carryOutAction];
}
```

You could have a NSArray property that holds NSNumbers containing Boolean values corresponding to each section and whether or not each section is enabled or not.  Then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath you could loop through the array and see if the Boolean variable is true.  If true, then carry out the action.

If you are worried about the highlighting of the row, you could handle that also with an IF statement easy enough.  Let me know if this is an issue for you.

Comment: See, the question is more so, how do I make that entire section not interactable? Thanks for your answer though. Makes sense.

Comment: When you say not interactable, what actions are you trying to prevent?  What I am suggesting is to make it **appear** that the cells in that section are not interactable by not carrying out actions or highlighting the rows in that section when users tap on the rows in that section.

Comment: Basically, if you tap on a section, then you shouldn't be able to interact with the stuff in that section at all.